# How to make links based on select option?

Tags: jquery

We use limited CMS (online store), so we must use scripts. The problem: we have a drop-down list (`select`) with different `options`, each product are different. We need to make buttons instead of the `select`. For example:

```
<select id="select-1">
  <option value="0">ААА</option>
  <option value="1">BBB</option>
  <option value="2">CCC</option> 
  <option value="3">DDD</option>
</select>
```

We need (using jQuery) make the buttons/links on the number of options, each button/link is a reference to the choice of a `value` and contains the text as it would be an appropriate `option`, so we should get:

```
<div id="links">
  <a href="?">AAA</a>
  <a href="?">BBB</a>
  <a href="?">CCC</a>
  <a href="?">DDD</a>
</div>
```

...where each link selects a appropriate `option`.

How to make such links based on jQuery?

Comment: Do you want to make it look like a select box, but only it's links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out:

```js
var links = [];
$("#select-1 option").each(function(){
  var opt = $(this);
  links.push("<a href='"+opt.val()+"'>"+opt.text()+"</a>")
});
$("#links").html(links.join())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select-1">
  <option value="0">ААА</option>
  <option value="1">BBB</option>
  <option value="2">CCC</option> 
  <option value="3">DDD</option>
</select>
<div id="links">

</div>
```

Comment: Testing on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lashchevsky/Lkbvf1sc/) - error: Please use POST request...